# How to install specific pod file without updating other dependencies?

Tags: ios, xcode, dependencies, cocoapods, podfile

I am trying to install 2 pod files without affecting/updating other dependencies in my pod file.

I tried with `pod install --no-repo-update` command. It is not working.

I want to install Fabric pod file when I try to install other dependencies are also updating and I don't want it because some dependencies are deprecated and it will show some warning and error, this is I don't want so I am trying to install pod without affecting and updating other pod files.

Here is the screenshot, in xcode I am getting 197 warnings. Before the installation of pod file there were 6 Xcode warnings.

```
 pod 'Fabric'
 pod 'Crashlytics'
```

[image]

Comment: What makes you think that other dependencies are also updating? Cause there is no chance that this command wouldn't work. It might INSTALL other dependencies but will not update in this case.

Comment: when I am installing the pod file, other 2 dependencies are updating. I don't know why this is happening. Because when I install the new profile the other dependency e.g ActionSheetPicker-3.0 pod files data showing some warnings and showing these files/code are deprecated.

Comment: can you attach the screenshot of the terminal that shows this issues?

Comment: check the screenshot. In the terminal, there is no issue. Only those 2 dependencies are installed.

Comment: @MallikarjunHanagandi did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

**You cannot install specific pod but you update specific pod.**

Reference 
https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html

**Pod install**

Use pod install to install new pods in your project. Even if you already have a Podfile and ran pod install before; so even if you are just adding/removing pods to a project already using CocoaPods.

**Pod Update**

Use pod update [PODNAME] only when you want to update pods to a newer versio

Answer (score -6):

To install new pod without updating others, just open up the existing file and add your pod file below the existing pods.

Now, go to terminal and open up your project and run command:

```
$ pod install
```

Note: This way, it will only add new pod without updating your existing pods.

Comment: this is not what OP asked